# Select all parents records in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Table structure:

```
id(int)    title(varchar)                 parent(int)
1          Accessories                    0
2          Man                            1
3          Women                          1
4          Watches                        2
5          New Watches                    4
6          Used Watches                   5
```

Suppose If I am on a forth or fifth level children category, How to retrieve all its parent categories in a query. Basically I want to show breadcrumbs hierarchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with:

```
select @start := id as 'id', title, parent
from table1
join 
(select @start := 0) temp
where parent = @start and id <= 4;
```

Note that without the `id < 4` check, you'll get the full tree from the "top" (`0`) to the "bottom" (`6`).

Checkout the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb03c/2), too.